# How to resolve mysql_fetch_assoc() problems

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

When i use the code below, im getting this error:
**Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource**

when returning the data, anyone can fix it? Thanks!

```
<?php
$mysql_server_name="localhost"; 
$mysql_username=""; 
$mysql_password=""; 
$mysql_database=""; 

$conn=mysql_connect($mysql_server_name, $mysql_username,
                    $mysql_password);
?>

<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
$arrays = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) { 
        if (!array_contains_key($key)) { 
            $arrays[$key] = array(); 
        } 
        $arrays[$key][] = $val; 
    } 
} 
?> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<?php 
foreach ($arrays as $key => $val) { 
    print 'var ' . $key . ' = ' . json_encode($val) . ";\r\n"; 
} 
?> 
</script>
```

Comment: Note that you should print the output of `mysql_error` only when developing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). Other than that, the error should be logged where only the admins can read it, and some other error message should be displayed to users. As for `SELECT *`, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select.

Comment: Good point @outis that's why `trigger_error` use is suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not  mysql_fetch_assoc problem but query problem
make it

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
```

and see actual error

Comment: yep, i got Notice: SELECT username FROM users, i got table name users, and theres one user, why i keep getting this error?

Comment: @sky can you paste exact error message here? Looks like some of it's text omitted. Can you look into page source for this?

Comment: Notice: SELECT username FROM users in /home/oiweiki1/public_html/yo2.us/error.php on line 14

heres the error message

Comment: @sky thats very strange. looks like an error occurred, but no error message. please try this, just another line below mysql_query: `echo htmlspecialchars(mysql_errno().mysql_error());`

Comment: lol, thanks for the help, but it seem like same. ; p

Answer (score 0):

Check the error messages of MySQL using [mysql_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users');
$error = mysql_error();
if ($error != '')
    die($error);
?>
```

Comment: die must die. as it break HTML and dirty practice at all

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do the Mysql connecting like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","passwd");
if (!$con)
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: using die is very bad practice. at least 500 HTTP error must be sent on the production server instead of sensitive mysql information